# Primefaces - methods not listed in 'actionListener'

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 4.0. I have a method in the Bean class, and I want to call it in a commandButton. When using Primeface's commandButton, Eclipse (Kepler) code completes the bean's name, as expected, but does not list the methods. The method is called, but there's no code completion for it. If I use the default commandButton, all the methods are listed (including 'equals' and 'hashCode').

In short, I'm getting code completion for some parts of the Primefaces tags, but not everything.

EDIT:

XHTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:inputText value="#{testBean.name}" id="name"  />
            <p:commandButton value="Print name" actionListener="#{testBean.printName}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

Bean

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4705029823018566258L;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printName(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }

}
```

Comment: post your xhtml and bean code.

Answer (score 0):

`printName()` isn't a `Listener object`. You need to have a `Listener object` handle the call and have the `action` done from there.

[Here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_actionListener.html) is some documentation to help you understand.

**EDIT**

This should work:

```
<p:commandButton>
       <f:actionListener/>
</p:commandButton>
```

If you have included the tag library and have downloaded the JAR and placed it in your `/WEB-INF/lib` :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.

As per the link: "Note: it is more common to implement an action listener using the "action" or "actionListener" attributes of a command component, such as h:commandButton or h:commandLink. The f:actionListener tag is useful for cases where you want to implement or reuse common action listener functionality across multiple components."

And the methods are listed in code completion with 'h:commandButton', with the usage I posted above.

Comment: I believe so. See EDIT @user3628930